# Staggered Column Labels in Silverlight Toolkit Chart

Tags: silverlight, xaml, charts, silverlight-toolkit

I need to style the chart control in silverlight toolkit to look like this
http://img375.imageshack.us/img375/3758/chartstyle.png

wherein the column labels are staggered. Can anybody lead me to the right direction on how to accomplish this task? Examples would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Keith

[Silverlight Chart http://img375.imageshack.us/img375/3758/chartstyle.png](http://img375.imageshack.us/img375/3758/chartstyle.png)

Comment: The image is taken from a mockup that one of the developers gave us. I dont know exactly how he made it but we want to mimic the staggered column labels on the chart (for the year).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out. Heres the XAML for the chart.

```
                    <toolkit:Chart
                    x:Name="barStyledChart"
                    Foreground="#FF579ED4"
                    Style="{StaticResource GreenFxChartStyle}"
                    FontSize="8"
                    Width="290"
                    Height="170"
                    BorderThickness="0">
                    <toolkit:Chart.Axes>
                        <toolkit:LinearAxis ShowGridLines="True" Orientation="X" Interval="1">
                            <toolkit:LinearAxis.GridLineStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="Line">
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#FF579ED4"></Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </toolkit:LinearAxis.GridLineStyle>
                        </toolkit:LinearAxis>
                        <toolkit:LinearAxis ShowGridLines="True" Orientation="Y" Location="Left" Minimum="0" Maximum="200">
                            <toolkit:LinearAxis.GridLineStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="Line">
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#FF032F50"></Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </toolkit:LinearAxis.GridLineStyle>
                        </toolkit:LinearAxis>
                    </toolkit:Chart.Axes>
                    <toolkit:ColumnSeries Background="#FF53C023" 
            AnimationSequence="FirstToLast" 
            DependentValuePath="X" IndependentValuePath="Y">
            <toolkit:ColumnSeries.ItemsSource>
                <PointCollection>
                    <Point>100,2000</Point>
                    <Point>105,2001</Point>
                    <Point>98,2002</Point>
                    <Point>88,2003</Point>
                    <Point>150,2004</Point>
                    <Point>125,2005</Point>
                    <Point>93,2006</Point>
                    <Point>112,2007</Point>
                    <Point>145,2008</Point>
                    <Point>165,2009</Point>
                    <Point>173,2010</Point>
                    <Point>168,2011</Point>
                    <Point>160,2012</Point>
                    <Point>164,2013</Point>
                    <Point>158,2014</Point>                                                                     
                </PointCollection>
            </toolkit:ColumnSeries.ItemsSource>
                        <toolkit:ColumnSeries.DataPointStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="toolkit:ColumnDataPoint">
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="toolkit:ColumnDataPoint">
                                            <Grid Width="10">
                                                <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1">
                                                    <Rectangle Fill="#FF53C023" Opacity=".8"></Rectangle>
                                                </Border>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </toolkit:ColumnSeries.DataPointStyle>
                    </toolkit:ColumnSeries>
                </toolkit:Chart>
```

and heres the XAML style for it

```
<Application
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit"
xmlns:datavis="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization"
xmlns:chartingprimitives="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.Primitives;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
xmlns:vsm="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=System.Windows"
xmlns:SampleData="clr-namespace:Expression.Blend.SampleData.ProgressionSequenceData" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Class="SilverlightChartScratchpad.App">
<Application.Resources>
    <SampleData:ProgressionSequenceData x:Key="ProgressionSequenceData" d:IsDataSource="True"/>

    <Style x:Key="GreenFxChartStyle" TargetType="toolkit:Chart" >
      <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
      <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
      <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
      <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10" />

        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.352,1.144" StartPoint="0.352,-0.161">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF0585D6" Offset="0.268"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF01336E" Offset="0.847"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>         

      <Setter Property="TitleStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
          <Style TargetType="toolkit:Title">
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="0"/>
          </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
      <Setter Property="LegendStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
          <Style TargetType="toolkit:Legend">
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="0"/>
          </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
      <Setter Property="ChartAreaStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
          <Style TargetType="Panel">
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="100" />
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="75" />
          </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
      <Setter Property="PlotAreaStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
          <Style TargetType="Grid">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
          </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="toolkit:Chart">
            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
              <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                  <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                  <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <toolkit:Title Content="{TemplateBinding Title}" Style="{TemplateBinding TitleStyle}" />
                <!-- Use a nested Grid to avoid possible clipping behavior resulting from ColumnSpan+Width=Auto -->
                <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <toolkit:Legend x:Name="Legend" Header="{TemplateBinding LegendTitle}" Style="{TemplateBinding LegendStyle}" Grid.Column="1" />
                  <chartingprimitives:EdgePanel x:Name="ChartArea" Style="{TemplateBinding ChartAreaStyle}">
                    <Grid Canvas.ZIndex="-1" Style="{TemplateBinding PlotAreaStyle}" />
                    <Border Canvas.ZIndex="10" BorderBrush="#FF032F50" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" />
                  </chartingprimitives:EdgePanel>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            </Border>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>

</Application.Resources>
```

The trick is to create two LinearAxis inside the Chart.Axes collection and hide the second axis label. Also, you need to set the interval which in my case is fixed to 1.